# Pegar json do postman e jogar em um objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Tenho **POST** e uso o **Postman** para testar. Monto a url e o body no **Postman**. Agora, quando eu testo em meu objeto na minha **Controller** vem **NULL**, e claro é porque eu não fiz corretamente. O que tenho que fazer?
Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class OptoutClientController : Controller
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Unsubscribe([FromBody]OptOutCliente cliente)
    { 
        return Ok();
    }

}
```

Model

```
public class OptOutCliente
{
    public Int64 Cpf { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public String Telefone { get; set; }
    public String Bandeira { get; set; }
    public String Canal { get; set; }
}
```

Body do Postman

```
{
"Cpf": "128907",
"Email": "p@p.com.br"
"Telefone": "971418418",
"Bandeira": "CB",
"Canal": "EML"
```

}

Como eu pego esse json do ouro lado, na minha controller?

**EDIT1**

Postman

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloca o código que o Postman gera pra entender melhor o que está acontecendo.

Comment: @MayconF.Castro, como assim? Não entendi. Quando coloco o break no Controller, não tenho nada, mas acho que é devido a estar faltando alguma coisa a mais e não sei o que é.

Comment: O breakpoint está sendo atingido lá na Controller, no método Unsubscribe?

Comment: Adiciona a print screen do Postman para vermos como está

Comment: Como está enviando essa requisição para o controller?

Comment: @Tony, coloquei a imagem do postman na edição

Comment: O conteudo do Body precisa ser o json indicado na pergunta e a URL terminaria em `/Unsubscribe`.  Por isto está dando null?

Comment: Decora o controller com `[Produces("application/json")]` e por favor adiciona a requisição que vc está fazendo no post para a rota `TesteClient/Unsubscribe`. Outro ponto verifica se a requisição no Postman está como "POST" e o "Body" configurado como JSON(application/json).

Comment: A variável cliente vem nula e estou esquecendo de alguma coisa, sei disso e não sei o que é. Da forma que está, cliente deve ou não ser NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido:

Meu json estava errado, faltou uma vírgula depois do email. Só achei estranho é o Postman não gritar, ele rodou tranquilamente. Pensei em tudo, menos no Postman, pois ele rodou e achei então que ele estava correto. Não atentei para o "X" vermelho nele.

Um amigo me disse assim: "**Quando você tenta de tudo e não acha solução, é porque o problema é uma besterinha, normalmente falta de atenção**".